# TaskGroup with synchronous functions

Tags: swift, asynchronous, async-await

Suppose I have a function which provides some longtime operations.

```
func foo(parameter: String)
```

This function is synchronous and I can't change it.

I need to run the function on array of parameters:

```
stringArray.forEach { foo($0) }
```

Obviously it requires a time.

I'd prefer to make an async function to make it asynchronously, like this:

```
func manyFoo(parameters: [String]) async {
    await withTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
        for parameter in parameters {
            group.addTask { foo(parameter: parameters) }
        }
    } 
}
```

But does it really execute `foo` simultaneously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ask:

> But does it really execute `foo` simultaneously?

Yes, it does, assuming `foo` is not actor-isolated. Obviously, if `foo` is isolated to any particular actor, then that will prevent parallel execution, despite the use of the task group. Then, again, if `foo` was actor isolated, then the compiler would warn you that you must `await` it.

FWIW, I added some `OSSignposter` logging, profiled it, and watched it in Instruments’ “Points of Interest” and “Swift Tasks” tools:

[image]

You can see that on my iPhone 13 Pro Max, I am getting six concurrent tasks.

That was with:

```swift
import os.log

private let poi = OSSignposter(subsystem: "Test", category: .pointsOfInterest)

class Experiment {
    let lock = NSLock()

    func foo(parameter: String) {
        let state = lock.withLock {
            let id = poi.makeSignpostID()
            return poi.beginInterval("foo", id: id, "\(parameter)")
        }

        …

        lock.withLock {
            poi.endInterval("foo", state)
        }
    }
}
```

---

Note, to see any material improvement in performance, you need to make sure there is enough work on each task to justify the modest overhead that concurrency introduces. E.g., if you have a million strings and each one takes 20 milliseconds each, it might actually be slower. So you might need to do “striding” (e.g., 100 tasks, each processing 10,000 strings).

Or if your tasks are all interacting with some shared resource, like a file, you might not be able to achieve any performance improvement at all.

We cannot comment further without knowing what your synchronous task is doing.